# how to change select tag values based on value coming from database

Tags: php, html, select

i want to change  tag option based on values coming from        database.if value is "1" i want to show different options and different for other values.

```
<<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>select</title>
    </head>
    <?php

    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {

        $number=$_POST['number'];
        //echo $number;
    if ($number=="1")
    { 

         echo "<select name='subject'>
         <option  value='1'>chemistry</option>
         <option  value='2'>Physics</option>
         <option  value='3'>Biology</option>
         <option  value='4'>Maths</option></select>"
    }
    else
    {
    echo "<select name='subject'>
          <option  value='5'>english</option>
          <option  value='6'>computer</option>
          <option  value='7'>Biology</option>
          <option  value='8'>Maths</option></select>"
    }
    ?>
    <body>
    <form method="post" action="select.php"> 
    <input type="text" name="number" value="">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
    </select>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Sorry, what is your question? I should point out you're missing a `}` from the end of the outer `if` condition.

Comment: this code is not working. i don't no why.i simply want to change options dynamically based on different values.basically the values would come from database.

Comment: In what way is it not working? Is it giving you an error? Is it not behaving in the way you intend?

Comment: i have added ";" at the end of both echo statements and also closed the if statement with "}" but still this is not working for me. it is not giving me errors but it is not behaving in a way i intend.

Comment: So... what is it doing? If even correcting the syntax isn't solving the problem, we'd need to know the manner in which it is failing in order to have any chance of explaining why that's happening.

Comment: thank you very much. now its working fine i just restart my php execution server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because

1. No closing `;` on here `<option  value='4'>Maths</option></select>"`
2. and here too `<option  value='8'>Maths</option></select>"`
3. First `if()` condition missing end `}`.

So final code is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>select</title>
</head>
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {

        $number = $_POST['number'];
        //echo $number;
        if ( $number == "1" )
        {

            echo "<select name='subject'>
         <option  value='1'>chemistry</option>
         <option  value='2'>Physics</option>
         <option  value='3'>Biology</option>
         <option  value='4'>Maths</option></select>";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<select name='subject'>
          <option  value='5'>english</option>
          <option  value='6'>computer</option>
          <option  value='7'>Biology</option>
          <option  value='8'>Maths</option></select>";
        }
    }

?>
<body>
<form method="post" action="select.php">
    <input type="text" name="number" value="">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Didn't spot the closing on the IF! Nicely spotted :)

Comment: sir, this code is still not performing the intend functionality for me.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the ; off of the end of both echos:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

    $number=$_POST['number'];
    //echo $number;
    if ($number=="1")
    { 

         echo "<select name='subject'>
         <option  value='1'>chemistry</option>
         <option  value='2'>Physics</option>
         <option  value='3'>Biology</option>
         <option  value='4'>Maths</option></select>";
    }
    else
    {
          echo "<select name='subject'>
          <option  value='5'>english</option>
          <option  value='6'>computer</option>
          <option  value='7'>Biology</option>
          <option  value='8'>Maths</option></select>";
     }
}
?>
```

Note: Sorry about poor layout, quick posting of answer!

Comment: And a `}` from the first `if` condition.

Comment: Yea I know, just noticed. Editing now ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $number=$_POST['number'];
    //echo $number;
    if ($number=="1")
    { 

        echo "<select name='subject'>
        <option  value='1'>chemistry</option>
        <option  value='2'>Physics</option>
        <option  value='3'>Biology</option>
        <option  value='4'>Maths</option></select>"; //missing ; here
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<select name='subject'>
        <option  value='5'>english</option>
        <option  value='6'>computer</option>
        <option  value='7'>Biology</option>
        <option  value='8'>Maths</option></select>";  //missing ; here
    }
}  // missing } here
```